# Same questions, different contexts. Are they duplicates?

Tags: discussion

The title say's everything, but let me explain:
Some questions are the exact same problem, but just in a little different context and a different language/engine. Are these duplicates?
Example: [Get points on a line between two points](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/23430/get-points-on-a-line-between-two-points/) and [Moving from A(x,y) to B(x1,y1) with constant speed?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/23447/moving-from-ax-y-to-bx1-y1-with-constant-speed)

I mean, even the asker giving the language, most of the problems are game logic based. So they can be solved no matter which language you're using. You can see that a large number of answers to this kind of question are in "pseudo-code".

Answer (score 3):

[Proper Handling for Different-Question-Same-Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57836/proper-handling-for-different-question-same-answer)

> If the questions are completely distinct and not duplicates then the correct response would be to answer the question on the question page. You should also link to your previous answer and *copy out the relevant information*.

Answer (score 1):

As for your example, the questions boil down to the same mathematical problem, but you'd only be able to realize this if you can at least partly answer the questions.

The difference between the questions may seem trivial to us, but the questions themselves are also trivial to us, though that doesn't invalidate them. The point of the matter is, are the questions sufficiently different to their intended target to warrant having both? It's close in this case, but I'd say yes. If nothing else we advertise more keywords to Google.